# Extract string from variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a variable which holds the values like

```
Feature/ABC-12345-apple-orange-mango
bugfix/ABC-52364-orange-mango
story/ABC-42361-juice-grape-banana
```

I am looking for a command to extract the value `ABC-[range of digits]` only.

Comment: All three lines are in the same variable?  Is `ABC-12345` a fixed string?

Comment: How should be the value recognised? Is it always "capital letters, dash, digits after a slash"?

Comment: Yes, ABC-[0-9] digits could be any combination of 5 digits

Comment: `...| grep -oP '[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{5}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
$ var='Feature/ABC-12345-apple-orange-mango
> bugfix/ABC-12345-apple-orange-mango
> story/ABC-12345-apple-orange-mango'
$ echo "$var" | grep -Eo 'ABC-[0-9]{5}'
ABC-12345
ABC-12345
ABC-12345
```

This will use grep with extended regex to search for any pattern that is `ABC-` followed by exactly 5 digits between 0-9.  The `-o` flag will make grep print only the match.

Comment: I have edited the question. sorry for the inconvenience.